# Multivariable. Global extrema in a set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier, hessian-matrix

> Given the function:  $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 6x - 4y +11$
>
> Determine the global extrema for f in the set $M = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} | x^2 + y^2 -4x \le 5\}$

So I know that continuous functions on a compact set have both a maximum and a minimum there. But I'm a bit stuck here. Am I supposed to solve this by using the hessian matrix? And how would I go about showing that the local extrema are also global extrema, is it because of the compactness?

$\nabla{f(x,y)} = (\partial_x f,\partial_y f) = (2x - 6, 2y -4)$

$\nabla{f(x,y) = (0,0)}$

$2x -6 = 0 \\2y - 4 = 0$

Stationary point a = [3, 2]

Comment: MathJax comment: for sets use `\{...\}` not `{...}`.

Comment: The local extremum either occur within the open set x^2 + y^2 - 4x < 5 or on the boundary where x^2 + y^2 - 4x = 5.  In the open set the gradient vanishes at the local extremum (otherwise you could increase/decrease the value of the function by perturbing a bit), on the boundary this is not necessarily true.  Thus find where the gradient is zero in the open set as a start.

Comment: both describe circles....... If you get a piece of paper and draw the circles as they are given, you will know almost everything

Comment: @WillJagy What exactly do you mean? The first is a function, an equation in *three* variables. How could that describe a circle? The second is a disc, not a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the global extrema of continuous $f$ on a compact subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you do two things:

**1.** *Interior.* Find all critical points of $f$ in the interior of $M$.

**2.** *Boundary.* Find potential global extrema of $f$ on the boundary of $M$. If this boundary is given by a constraint (e.g., $x^2+y^2-4x=5$, as yours is), then you may use Lagrange multipliers.

Evaluate $f$ at all the points found in the two steps above. The largest (respectively, smallest) of these values is the global maximum (resp., global minimum) value of $f$ on $M$.

You have completed part **1**.

*(Note: Since you're asking about global extrema on a compact subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is absolutely no reason to do anything for local extrema. If you wanted to know what happens at the critical point $(3,2)$, then fine---test it using the second-derivative test. But you are asking about global extrema; the second-derivative test is useless for this task.)*

Comment: Is there a way to check for the boundary without Lagrange Multipliers? We haven't covered them in lectures yet.

Comment: Yes there is. The boundary of $M$ is $(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 9$ (complete the square), a circle with center $(2,0)$ and radius $3$, so it can be parameterized by $x(t)=2+3\cos t$, $y(t)=3\sin t$, $0\leq t \leq 2 \pi$. Then for every $t$ in $[0,2\pi]$, $F(t) = f(x(t), y(t))$ is the value of $f$ at the point $(x(t),y(t))$ on $M$. Ah, so finding the global extrema of $f$ on $\mathrm{bd}(M)$ is therefore the same problem as finding the global extrema of the one-variable function $F$ on $[0,2\pi]$. So find these extrema for $F$ on $[0,2\pi]$. Make a conclusion about the extrema of $f$ on $\mathrm{bd}(M)$.

Comment: Another approach: The boundary of $M$ is $\mathrm{bd}(M) = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2+y^2-4x=5\}$ (circle w/ center $(2,0)$, radius $3$), which (solve for $y$) is the union of $\{(x,y)\mid y=\sqrt{5+4x-x^2}\}$ and $\{(x,y)\mid y=-\sqrt{5+4x-x^2}\}$. On the first of those two sets, $f$ is given by $f(x,\sqrt{5+4x-x^2}\,)$ for $-3\leq x\leq 5$; on the second set, $f$ is given by $f(x,-\sqrt{5+4x-x^2}\,)$ for $-3\leq x\leq 5$. So you have two problems: find the global extrema of $f(x,\sqrt{5+4x-x^2}\,)$ on $[-3,5]$, and  find the global extrema of $f(x,-\sqrt{5+4x-x^2}\,)$ on $[-3,5]$. Compare results.